# How to output files to the parent of their source directory using Webpack in Gulp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, webpack

So far I have this code, which I got [from here](https://github.com/shama/webpack-stream#multiple-entry-points):

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var webpack = require('webpack-stream');
var named = require('vinyl-named');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gulp.src('*/lib/app.js', { base: '.' })
    .pipe(named())
    .pipe(webpack())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

My folder structure is like:

```
site1/lib/app.js
site2/lib/app.js
```

I want to create the output files like the following, with each file containing only their respective lib/app.js file's code (and any require()s made in them):

```
site1/app.js
site2/app.js
```

However, the code I have now just outputs to the project's root directory. I've tried several combinations, such as removing the `{ base: '.' }`, but nothing works. If I remove the `named()` and `webpack()` pipes, though, then the current code actually outputs to the correct directory. So, in the process, it seems like perhaps Webpack loses the originating directory information?

Also, it possible to get a solution that also works with Webpack's "watch: true" option, so that compiling modified files is quick, rather than using Gulp to always iterate through every single file on every file change?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to create a `app.js` for each site that packs **only** the code for that site (and not the others).

In that case you can use [`gulp-foreach`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-foreach) to effectively iterate over all your `app.js` files and send each one down its own stream. Then you can use the node.js built-in [`path` module](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) to figure out where the parent directory for each `app.js` file is and write it there with `gulp.dest()`.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var webpack = require('webpack-stream');
var named = require('vinyl-named');
var foreach = require('gulp-foreach');
var path = require('path');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gulp.src('*/lib/app.js')
    .pipe(foreach(function(stream, file) {
      var parentDir = path.dirname(path.dirname(file.path));
      return stream
        .pipe(named())
        .pipe(webpack())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(parentDir));
    }));
});
```

If you want to use `webpack({watch:true})` you'll have to use a different approach. The following uses [`glob`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) to iterate over all the `app.js` files. Each `app.js` file is again send down its own stream, however this time all the streams are [merged](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-stream) before being returned.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var webpack = require('webpack-stream');
var named = require('vinyl-named');
var path = require('path');
var merge = require('merge-stream');
var glob = require('glob');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  return merge.apply(null, glob.sync('*/lib/app.js').map(function(file) {
    var parentDir = path.dirname(path.dirname(file));
    return gulp.src(file)
      .pipe(named())
      .pipe(webpack({watch:true}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(parentDir));
  }));
});
```

Comment: If I do this, then will Webpack's "watch: true" work, or will it not work because it creates a new watcher for each stream?

Comment: Won't work, because the first watcher will block everything. You'd have to use the regular `gulp.watch()` instead of `webpack({watch:true})`. If you really want to use `webpack({watch:true})` you'll have to merge the individual streams (see my edit).

Comment: Okay thanks. Also, is it possible, to modify the source files by running them through gulp-coffee or gulp-concat, and then somehow passing that to Webpack? I get the error `// Unhandled stream error in pipe.` when I try that.

Comment: Different topic. Open a new question for that.

Comment: Okay thanks. [Here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38253175/pass-gulp-sources-to-gulp-coffee-gulp-concat-and-webpack-stream).