# Pass Gulp sources to gulp-coffee, gulp-concat, and webpack-stream

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, gulp, webpack, concatenation

I have the code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var webpack = require('webpack-stream');
var coffee = require('gulp-coffee');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('webpack', function() {
  gulp.src('*/lib/*.coffee', { base: '.' })
    .pipe(coffee({ bare: true }))
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(webpack())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

However, it doesn't work, when it reaches `webpack()`. How can I make it so that the content passed from `concat()` to `webpack()` works successfully?

I also assume that if I removed the `concat()` pipe, and went straight from `coffee()` to `webpack()`, then I'd end up with multiple files processed by `webpack()` rather than a single one, right?

I tried using `coffee-loader` for Webpack, but for some reason it outputs content with `bare: false` (when I look at the output file), even though in the actual package, it appears that it's hardcoded to output with `bare: true`. So that's why I'm using `gulp-coffee` instead.